# Mapping multiple Tables to one Entity

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I work on a legacy database that stores Users in one of two tables (`ActiveUsers`, `InactiveUsers`). In my DbContext I defined the following DbSets to work with the two Usertables:

```
public DbSet<User> ActiveUsers{ get; set; }
public DbSet<User> InactiveUsers{ get; set; }
```

How can I map the `User` entity to the tables? I'm stuck with these Mappings:

```
// OK
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("ActiveUsers");

// Overwrites the mapping above :(
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("InactiveUsers");
```

I think I need to configure the DbSets somehow...

PS: [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738537.aspx) seems to solve my problem for "classic" EF with an EDMX.

Comment: You could derive a new entity type from User that would not have any properties and map it to the InactiveUsers table.

Comment: I've done that :) But I thought there could be a better option and posted this on SO

Comment: CodeFirst does not support MEST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pawel pointed out:

> CodeFirst does not support MEST